# JQuery Change Checkboxes in Dynamic Table

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I am creating a table based on rows returned from a MySQL query using PHP:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_results)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[Title]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[Name]</td>";
    echo "<td><input class='row-$i' id='one-$i' type='checkbox' ($row[check_one]==1 ? 'checked' : '')/></td>";
    echo "<td><input class='row-$i' id='two-$i' type='checkbox' ($row[check_two]==1 ? 'checked' : '')/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++
}
```

What I want to have happen is if the first checkbox is checked and you check the second one, the first checkbox becomes unchecked. I was originally going to use radio buttons to accomplish this, but the user also needs to be able to freely check or uncheck the first check box (ie both can be unchecked at one time), so radio buttons won't work. So what I need to do is detect `change` for `two-$i` elements, but am not sure how to do so for a dynamic element. Under normal circumstances the JQuery would be:

```
$('#two').change(function(){...});
```

So how can I modify this to work on the dynamic ids?

Comment: When you're generating dynamic elements of same type, you must have to specify the prefix same followed by the numeric digit like `'ele1','ele2',...'eleN'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function change(val)
{
  if(val=='one-1')
    document.getElementById('two-2').checked=false
  else
    document.getElementById('one-1').checked=false
}
```

```html
First<input type="checkbox" id="one-1" value="one-1" onClick="change(this.value);"/><br>
Second<input type="checkbox" id="two-2" value="two-2" onClick="change(this.value);"/>
```

This will help you.
Happy Coding.

Comment: Not sure why I hadn't thought of onClick(). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: but this is static example there should be a dynamic solution if there are checkbox more than 2

Comment: like this $('input:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');

Comment: By changing the parameters of change(val) to change(type, num) I achieved the dynamic aspect.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table > input[type='checkbox']").on("click",function(){
         $('#table > input:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="table">
  First<input type="checkbox" id="one-1" value="one-1" /><br>
  Second<input type="checkbox" id="two-2" value="two-2" /><br>
  Third<input type="checkbox" id="two-2" value="two-2" />

</div>
```

Comment: Considering I use checkboxes else where on the page, wouldn't this have a side effect of changing those?

Comment: you can also use  $('#table > input:checkbox') to restrict it